# Little equivalence-relation problem

Tags: combinatorics, equivalence-relations

If $U=\{1,2,\ldots,1000\}$ and $A = \mathbb P(U) - \{ \emptyset \}$, the following relation $R$ is defined in $A$

$$XRY \Leftrightarrow (\min X = \min Y) \wedge (\max X = \max Y)$$

Calculate $\#[\{101,201\}]$

(The number of elements in the equivalence class of $\{101,201\}$)

What I did was simply use that:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{100} {100\choose i}=2^{100}$$

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every set in the equivalence class contains $101$ and $201$ as members, and may or may not contain others in the set $\{102,\ldots,200\}$.  So you're just counting subsets of $\{102,\ldots,200\}$.

The number of members of the set $\{102,\ldots,200\}$ is $99$, so it would just be the number of subsets of a set of size $99$, i.e. it's $2^{99}$.